# Getting the user_id through Foursquare Api V2

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I'm working on a foursquare integration for a social good website, and I have everything working as I want it to, however I want to retrieve and store users foursquare user_id's so others can search for their friend. I've been searching all day, but I can't seem to find an end point, am I missing something? Or does this has to be done through user search? What is then best to use, as I have their email, and full name.

I am using jmathai's foursquare-async php libary. I think it should be easy but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. To get an users' details you should use the end point "users/self". I had tried this before but got an error message. I think that was related to something else now.

After authenticating two lines are simply enough:

```
<?php       
$fsObj->get("/users/self");  
print_r($creds->response);  
?php>
```

This gives an json array containing all relevant information on the user, including last checkins, name, and id. 'self' can here also be replaced by any user id you're authorized for on that moment.

For more information I'd recommend to visit [Foursquare Api website](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore.html#req=users/self)